# Cordova plugin for linkedin login

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm doing app development by using apache Cordova. I just want to know, is there any Cordova plugin which implements the native LinkedIn sign into my app.

Example: If I installed Linkedin app means my app should recognize the user who signed in that app. If not just redirect to the LinkedIn sign in page.

Answer (score 0):

install inAppBrowser plugin into your cordova/ionic app. and use OAuth feature of ionic/ngCordova framework.

For more guide have a look at

http://blog.ionic.io/oauth-ionic-ngcordova/

and

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/

Comment: For now, I'm using ng Cordova only. Also in my device, I have LinkedIn app. Whenever I try login using LinkedIn it shows LinkedIn login page via inAppbrowser plugin

Comment: I need a plugin, that will fetch the user data if that device has installed the LinkedIn app in Cordova.